# How to resolve this channel issue from WMQ?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, connection-reset

Below is the related part from a QMGR log file about a WMQ channel issue:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-7-23 10:35:25 - Process(340.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqchl.exe)
AMQ9206:  Error sending data to host 86.0.223.5(1602) 。

EXPLANATION:
An error occurred sending data over TCP/IP to 86.0.223.5(1602). This may be due to
a communications failure.
ACTION:
The return code from the TCP/IP(send) call was 10054 X('2746'). Record these
values and tell your systems administrator.  
----- amqccita.c : 2612 -------------------------------------------------------
2012-7-23 10:35:25 - Process(340.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqchl.exe)
AMQ9999: Channel program ended abnormally. 

EXPLANATION: 
Channel program 'CZWJNS.CZWJCZ' ended abnormally. 
ACTION: 
Look at previous error messages for channel program 'CZWJNS.CZWJCZ' in the 
error files to determine the cause of the failure.  
----- amqrccca.c : 834 --------------------------------------------------------
2012-7-23 10:35:35 - Process(3616.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqchl.exe)
AMQ9002: Channel “CZWJNS.CZWJCZ' is starting。

EXPLANATION：
Channel “CZWJNS.CZWJCZ' is starting。
ACTION：
None。 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-7-23 10:40:35 - Process(3616.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqchl.exe)
AMQ9206:  Error sending data to host 86.0.223.5(1602) 。

EXPLANATION:
An error occurred sending data over TCP/IP to 86.0.223.5(1602). This may be due to
a communications failure.
ACTION:
The return code from the TCP/IP(send) call was 10054 X('2746'). Record these
values and tell your systems administrator.   
----- amqccita.c : 2612 -------------------------------------------------------
2012-7-23 10:40:35 - Process(3616.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqchl.exe)
AMQ9999: Channel program ended abnormally. 

EXPLANATION: 
Channel program 'CZWJNS.CZWJCZ' ended abnormally. 
ACTION: 
Look at previous error messages for channel program 'CZWJNS.CZWJCZ' in the 
error files to determine the cause of the failure.  
----- amqrccca.c : 834 --------------------------------------------------------
2012-7-23 10:40:45 - Process(4848.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqchl.exe)
AMQ9002: Channel “CZWJNS.CZWJCZ' is starting。

EXPLANATION：
Channel “CZWJNS.CZWJCZ' is starting。
ACTION：
None。
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Right now, the situation is that the target channel (`CZWJNS.CZWJCZ`) can finally run, but only after a few retry attempts. It keeps happening often. All the messages can be delivered to the target queue in the remote QMGR host successfully. However, they're always delayed due to the multiple retry attempts.

I've searched through the internet for the return code `10054` and it means the connection has been reset by the peer.

My WMQ version is 6.0.10 on Windows 2003.

Comment: Can you provide the error log for the *other* QMgr as well?  Also, what are the channel definitions on both sides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Connection reset by peer" means that something between this node and the other node closed the connection. The cause can range from dodgy/noisy network, to firewall timing out, to channel exits that refuse the connection, or many other causes.

The key to diagnosis in these cases is to narrow down the cause. This requires looking at the error logs on both QMgrs (or the client and QMgr) for the same event. In the case of a channel exit, a look at the channel definitions on both sides reveals whether such an exit is in place but if it is then you need to look at the exit's configuration and logs as well.

If the problem is in the network, the error logs from both QMgrs will show similar errors. However if one QMgr closed the connection intentionally then you will see that in its log files.

Comment: Thanks very much @T.Rob i've already asked customer double check on the network configuration. Hope they can get some clue.

Comment: Were you able to get the error logs from the other QMgr? At this point you'd probably need to recreate the problem and capture new sets of logs from both sides since they probably will have rolled off by now.  Can you post the channel defs from both QMgrs as well?  That will help identify if exits are in play on either side.

Comment: we can't get the error logs from the other QMGR which belongs to another organization. anyway, thx @T.Rob

Comment: I forgot to mention - V6 of WMQ is out of service as of September.  You are planning to upgrade soon, right?  The newer versions, especially V7.5, give MUCH better error messages in general and have better channel stability and performance.

Comment: V7.5 already released? OMG, i still thought 7.1 was the latest one. sure, we have to upgrade. otherwise, that EOS SE service would be very expensive, you know :-)